# pointer arithmetic (char*) &a[1] - (char *)&a[0] == 4

Tags: c, pointers, casting

If a is an int array, `(char*) &a[1] - (char *)&a[0]` is equal to 4, while `&a[1] - &a[0]` is equal to 1. why is that?

Comment: 4-bytes alignment? After pointers transformation in first case you get right information.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is in terms of the size of the objects pointed to.

Comment: so once it's casted, the compiler think the two elements are bytes apart and this difference means there are 4 chars in between, so it returns a 4. While in the non-casting case, the compiler thinks that the two elements are 4 bytes apart but they are 1 int element apart, so it returns 1?

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic, it's just like what happen when you do subtraction of pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer math operates on the size of the data structure its pointing to.  This is because if I do this:

```
int array[10] ;
int * p = array ;

p ++ ;
```

I want `p` pointing at the second int, not some memory halfway in between two elements.

So `&a[1]` is four bytes apart from `&a[0]` but asking it `&a[1] - &a[0]` asks how many `ints` apart it is.  When you cast it to `char` you ask for the math in terms of the size of `char`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
&a[1] - &a[0]
```

since a is an int array, an implicit (int *) pointer is assumed, that is

```
(int *)&a[1] - (int *)&a[0]
```

Hence since both are of type pointer to int , their difference gives 1.

But when you do-

```
(char*) &a[1] - (char *)&a[2]
```

assuming int is 4 bytes and char is 1 byte on your compiler, the difference will be four since each element of a is int and has four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem about programmers to treat pointers as **just** address. This is wrong approach. For the compiler to create proper low level code it must know something more about pointer than just the memory location that it points to. That additional info is the size of object a pointer is pointing to. That all is contained in pointer type and is necessary for pointer aruthmetic. For example:

```
int a[25] ;
int *i_ptr = a;

printf("address of 1st element %d\n", a);
printf("address of 1st element %d\n", &a[0]);

// address of first element + sizeof(int)
printf("address of 2nd element %d\n", a+1);

// address of first element + sizeof(int)    
printf("address of 2nd element %d\n", &a[1]);

// this one is tricky
// address of first element + sizeof(25*int) ie sizeof(the whole array)
printf("address of JUST AFTER THE ARRAY %d\n", &a+1);
```

Last is very tricky and most programmers do not even know about it. Although **a** is pointing to the first element of array and has type of array element **&a** is something completely different. It also keeps addres of array's first element (ie. array start) but it's type is different suggesting compiler that pointer arithmetic on it will be based on array size not element size.

gives:

```
address of 1st element 2881388               +0
address of 1st element 2881388               +0
address of 2nd element 2881392               +4
address of 2nd element 2881392               +4
address of JUST AFTER THE ARRAY 2881488    +100
```

Every time you obtain address of something with ***&*** operator it has associated type with it allowing later calculations with that type of pointer.

Keep in mind that there is a pointer ***void **** that does not have any type info associated with it and you canot perform arithmetic on it.