# C - int array to char* conversion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, type-conversion

I have a question to the conversion of `int` array to `char*`. The following code has the output `23`. But I don't really understand why. Can someone explain it to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t* p = (uint32_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));    
    uint32_t array[9] = {42, 5, 23, 82, 127, 21, 324, 3, 8};

    *p = *((char*)array+8);
    printf("1: %d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pointer arithmetic (char\*) &a\[1\] - (char \*)&a\[0\] == 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486661/pointer-arithmetic-char-a1-char-a0-4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of a uint32 is 32 bits, or 4 bytes. When you do `(char*)array+8`, you cast the array into an array of char, and take the eighth character. Here, the eighth character contains the beginning of the integer `23`, which fits into a char.

Answer (score 4):

```
*p = *((char*)array+8*sizeof(uint32_t)
```

to move to array[8]
in your example you are only moving 8 bytes forward

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it, you have casted the array to `char*`. Where sizeof char is 1B.
Which means usage pointer arithmetics in this case `+8` doesnt move you `8*sizeof(uint32_t)` to nineth element of array, but only 8 Bytes (`8*sizeof(char)`).

Since `uint32_t` has 4 Bytes, you have moved to first byte of 3rd element 23.

First you have to use pointer arithmetics on `uint32_t` array and after that cast it to char, like

```
*p = (char)*(array+8);  // Prints 8
```